# Set Explorer layout for all users

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-server-2012, multiple-users

For a single folder or set of folders recursively set the layout to include additional columns and make those changes for any user that logs on.

We have a server(Windows 2012) that has a folder that holds emails. In Windows Explorer I have setup all the extra columns to show Subject, From, To etc but how can I make those customisations available to any other users that RDP on to the server?

I have no desire to affect all folders or make it the Default configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge this is only possible by copying your configuration to the "default user profile" and then deleting everyone else profile so they grab the default profile at their next login. This will cause them to loose all customization they might have done and all the file they have in their profile (my document, my picture, desktop)...

Comment: Can you point me to any documentation on doing that?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825135.aspx